# Images sent thruogh visualforce email templates

Tags: visualforce-template

The requirement is like: we want to sent some images in the emails generated. Email will be generated from visualforce email templates, so we need to add the images in visualforce email templates. 
 Read lot many sites with the answer

-> Store the images in document tab and then access images through urls.

Can anyone suggest some other approach which more configurable than documents tab. 
why we can not use static resources? if yes, please guide me how can I use it with static resources.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you wish to keep everything contained within Salesforce I do not believe you have a better option as the Document tab. As the documentation clearly states that static resources or page styles cannot be referenced.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_email_templates_stylesheets.htm?SearchType=Stem

For now, I believe we are stuck with the Documents tab, or storing images externally.

Comment: Yes I agree, as we don't have other option than documents tab... or else if possible, we have to design images in html template manually... :)